# Laravel 5.8 - I try to install node_module and am getting 'error permission denied'

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I install the Laravel 5.8 version, install npm, and then I am getting an error related to permissions.

I also used `sudo nmp install`, but I am again getting an error:

> webpack cli 3.* is not installed

and an Node.js permission denied error displayed so many times. How can I resolve this?

Comment: run this from your home directory `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

Comment: And then delete the node_modules and re-run `npm install`

Comment: Thanks @VikashPathak sir for quick response